# Nodejs error occurs with undefined options after submitting request | NodeJS | ExpressJS | MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm sending request to Nodejs server using ExpressJs with MySQL.
The first request is successfull, but others are returning with `error status code 400` and some undefined properties. Why is this happen and how can be fixed ?

Side note: after check in my gitbash terminal with curl command for the server with the particular port I notice that returns `500` with other options. Could this be a reason and how can solve it ?

server.js

```
const app = require('./app');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const pc = require('picocolors');

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

// START THE SERVER
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(pc.cyan(`App running on port ${port}...`));
});
```

truckController.js

```
exports.truckOfferFile = catchAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send('Empty object provided');
    }

    let response = await pool.query("INSERT INTO `truck_covers` SET ?", req.body, function (error, results, fields) {
      pool.release();
      return results;
    });

  return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    status: "success",
    message: "File information saved sucessfully!",
    offerId: response[0].insertId
  });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('error', error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      message: error
    });
  }
});
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So to resolve that I try a couple of different approaches for example:

```
function main(sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
      if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(sql, (errt, rows) => {
        connection.release(); // return the connection to pool
        if (errt) throw err;
        // console.log(rows);
        resolve(rows);
      });
    });
  });
}

const response = async function queries() {
  let Q = "INSERT INTO `truck_covers` SET ?";
  let result = await main(Q);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: @user1191247 
I do posted images of errors and other code, already.
Could you please confirm me that you can see them ?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).